# VHDL can't matching context of call for to_unsigned in user defined function

Tags: vhdl, unsigned, quartus

I'm using Quartus Prime Pro.
I'm dealing with a function as such:

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

function round_resize (a : unsigned; b : integer) return unsigned is
  variable c : signed (a'length - 1 downto 0); --problem child
  variable d : signed (b - 1 downto 0);
begin
  c := a + to_signed(2**(b-2), a'length);
  d := to_unsigned(c(c'length-2 downto (c'length-b-1)));
  return d;
end function;
```

But I get the error:

> Error(13643): VHDL error at file.vhd(109): can't determine definition of operator ""+"" -- found 0 possible definitions

So I changed the problem child to this:

```
c := to_unsigned( a + to_signed(2**(b-2), a'length), a'length);
```

But I get the following error:

> Error(13815): VHDL Qualified Expression error at cpmmod.vhd(110): to_unsigned type specified in Qualified Expression must match signed type that is implied for expression by context

What else can I try to make this work?

Comment: Well you could [respect types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z9aA.jpg) but it's unclear why your doing all this.

Comment: @user1155120 I really don't get why you are not putting this in an answer... instead you are just linking to an image of the code which has an answer! Why go though all this effort, but still refuse to post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to add an unsigned with a signed value. You could convert one of the two to get the same type on the variables before add them.

Answer (score 3):

Nathanael is correct.

To understand what is happening, you need to understand two concepts:

**i) operators in VHDL are functions**

When you use an operator, you are really calling a function. In the `numeric_std` package, there are many definitions of various operators. For example, one definition of the `+` operator is

```
  function "+" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
```

**ii) VHDL uses *overloading***

If you look in the `numeric_std` package, you will see many definitions of `+` operators:

```
  function "+" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
  function "+" (L, R: SIGNED) return SIGNED;
  function "+" (L: UNSIGNED; R: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED;
  function "+" (L: NATURAL; R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
  function "+" (L: INTEGER; R: SIGNED) return SIGNED;
  function "+" (L: SIGNED; R: INTEGER) return SIGNED;
```

Each has a different combination of argument types and return types. The compiler can determine which one to call by this combination (called the *signature*). This idea is called *overloading*. It only works if there is exactly one possible function to call. If there is more than one, the compiler doesn't know which one to call; if there is less than one, the compiler doesn't have a function to call...

...and that is your problem. If you look at the signatures of the `+` operator functions in `numeric_std` listed above, you will see that there are no `+` operators defined which combine `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED` types. Therefore, in your case, the compiler has no function to call and overloading fails.

You need to think carefully about the arithmetic you wish to implement and then convert everything to either `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` as you see fit. You do do that easily using *type conversions*, because `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED` are *closely related types* (they are both arrays of `std_logic` indexed by an integer).